# How to run application in cygwin without blocking the shell

Tags: cygwin

I would like to open applications in cygwin, e.g. notepad etc, without the shell blocking.  Is there a way of doing this?

For example, typing in `notepad myfile.txt` will open notepad, and the cygwin shell will be unavailable until notepad is closed.  I'd like cygwin to remain responsive whilst notepad is open.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using some UNIX shell such as `sh`, then

```
notepad &
```

should work.

Remember: If you're using another shell, then other rules apply. `cmd` won't block for GUI applications, unless `start /wait` is used. But on UNIX-likes there is no distinction between console programs and GUI programs. They all run interactively on the console unless detached by starting them with `&` after the command.